# Acceptable way to migrate a huge application away from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii, yii2

We have a huge website written in a old (7 years old) modified version of CodeIgniter and we're stuck on php 5.4 because of that. This app started very very small but increased a huge deal in these years and we're doing changes to it on a daily basis, so the code is not quite clean, we have hacks everywhere, many versioned assets loaded at same time because they are dependencies of the layout, etc... anyway, not pretty at all.

We would like to move to Yii 2 because that's something we're very familiar with and we have other apps written in it, it supports higher versions of PHP, composer, etc etc, you get the point.

We don't have an army of devs so that some of us can rewrite the app from scratch and some of us continue developing the current one, thus i think we should start rewriting small parts of it and using nginx would redirect the traffic to the newly rewritten parts, and do so till the entire rewrite is done, basically for a while, both apps would run in parallel sharing same database but accessing various urls would access one app or the other.

Has any of you gone this road and can share the experience, some pointers, etc ?

Comment: I'm going to push back on your basic premise - Codeigniter 3 runs on PHP 7, so you are not 'stuck' on PHP 5.4 . Codeigniter 3 also supports Composer. If you are using Codeigniter 2 its actually very simple to upgrade to CI 3, there are very few breaking changes.

Comment: you've missed a point, the fact that firstly we're using an ancient version of CI and secondly that we had to modify it a lot for our needs, so an upgrade of CI is out of question. And also, we're not that keen into using CI anymore.

Comment: Otherwise consider which of parts of your application you could migrate over to an API style of data exchange. In other words to send / receive json objects or arrays. Then you can have parts of your application on a completely different server with a more recent version of PHP.

Comment: yes, that can be an option too, though i'd prefer avoiding the api calls overhead if possible.

Comment: it might sound complicated but especially for non public tasks - its really simple to set up and very flexible. and once you have a format you like its very fast to set up. being able to use other servers is also a huge help as you test your code etc. i used this to transition a big e-commerce app from 5.2 to 5.6.

Comment: Even with a tiny development team, bad practice is going to come back and bite you every time. Not upgrading CI, allowing un-maintainable hacks to go into production, loosing control of your architecture, this is all your fault and not the fault of CI. However Yii is perfectly good too. I would take this time to re-assess where you are with your app. Write some decent plans, and start coding again from scratch. Plan a release date and bin your old system. Otherwise you are going to spend as long coding the transition as you are coding the new system. And learn from your mistakes.